# Self Hosted Integration Runtime is unavailable in AzureDataFactory pipeline

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am creating self-hosted integration runtime service in Azure Data Factory but getting "azure data factory self hosted integration runtime unavailable" error. I have setup firewall access to my machine iP but still no luck. Does anyonce face this issue or any suggestion around...

Even Integration runtime(self hosted) express setup is showing error

"An error occurred when doing express setup: Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.. "[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZbAh.png)

Comment: Did you look in the event log?   This is likely still a firewall issue.  You can check the local Windows firewall.  The details on paths that need to be opened are here...  This is still a firewall issue.  You could check the local Windows Firewall as well.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime#ports-and-firewalls

Comment: Thanks Nate...Yes it is firewall issue due...